# Spring JpaTransactionManager and Jackrabbit on the same database

Tags: oracle, spring, jpa, jackrabbit

We are using JPA in our project (using Oracle Database)  and also want to use apache JackRabbit API. But If you use a database- persistence manager, the configured database connection must not be under the control of an external transaction manager. Jackrabbit implements distributed XA transaction support on a higher level, and expects to be in full control of the underlying database connection.

What is the solution for this problem?